# how to make Autorun Setup for win Applicatin Visual studio to installing sql server and .net framework and ...?

Tags: vb.net

how to make Autorun installing for win Applicatin Visual studio 
that installing .net framework and sql server or all needed?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project's properties -> Publish -> Prerequisites... In there you'll find a list that manages the prerequisites for that project and such marked prerequisites will be automatically added to the "setup project".

I'm not sure if this will actually install the dependency... but I think it will, at the very least, present the user with a prerequisite error and give it a download link.